# What is the name and availability of this lure?

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle

Found this Mepps jig/spinner in my Dad's tackle box and don't know its age:

[image]

It has a metal jig body, flat bottom, black with white eyes, single hook with a week guard. Trailing is a spinner blade with "MEPPS" stamped on one side and "AGLIA LONG Made in France" on the other.  Weight without the added Mister Twister grub is 3/8 oz. I would like to know what the lure is called and how common it is.  I haven't been able to find anything similar on the internet, even on several Mepps sites.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the brand?

Answer (score 2):

I just googled `Mepps` and `aglia long` - and got [this](https://www.mepps.com/information/aglia-long-2/135#AL2%20HFT), it's not identical in colour but is in shape and manufacturer.

Mepps is a fairly well known brand of fishing lures. This seems to be one of their more popular products. It is a willow leaf shape for spinning in fast flowing water.

The number `2` indicates the weight of the lure - 1/4 oz according to the website linked. They come in a range of different hook combinations, including ones with additional minnow-like lures attached to the hook.

Comment: But that particular Mepps Aglia Long is an "in-line" spinner, doesn't have a jig head, and has a treble hook.  On mine, the spinner in not in line with the hook, rather the single hook and blade are 2 separate branches from jig head.

Comment: @DavidHoppe - yours looks like it has been modified a bit given the black plastic melted over the attachment. If you have a look at the options on the page under style - they have a single hook type too. You can always try their [contact us](https://www.mepps.com/customer-service/contact-us/) page and see if they know more about it.

Comment: Last word?  A Mepps U.S. rep was stumped too, and recommended contacting France.  A France rep said the soft bait is an OOP product they called a "Bad Dude."  The blade is Aglia Long as labeled, still used, and the jig body must have been custom made as he, having worked "many years" at Mepps, had never seen one like it.

Comment: @DavidHoppe good to know. Fishermen are always trying to adapt their rigs to the conditions they face, so I wouldn't be surprised at all to find that it was customized.

Comment: Correction, it was "Mean Dude."  And it does have recognizable differences from a Mister Twister, so I was wrong there, too.